# Is it possible to have a notification in my app when user connects to bluetooth while in background?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, ios-bluetooth

I want to achieve a certain behavior in my application - regardless of the app's state. When a user connects to a bluetooth device from his phone, I want to get a notification in my app and do something. I tried to achieve this using `AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification` but it seems to work only when the app is in the foreground. I read that the events `newDeviceAvailable` and `oldDeviceUnavailable` will be triggered in the background only if my app plays music. However my app doesn't - I just want to know that there're a connection change. Are there any manipulations that can be done, to listen to those events even if the app is in the foreground/killed?

Comment: I'm not sure Apple wants you doing this :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Detect Bluetooth connection/disconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284737/ios-detect-bluetooth-connection-disconnection)