# How to detect possible audio outputs in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth

Is it possible to detect audio outputs like airpods, regular headphones or remote speakers connected to the device and get their properties?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996269/headphones-plugin-out-detection-in-swift

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. The linked question is about detecting route changes, not enumerating all possible routes.

Comment: While this is impossible, I'm curious what you plan to do with this information. There are important privacy reasons that this information isn't available (currentRoute already leaks some important privacy information, but some of it is necessary). What problem are you trying to solve; there may be another solution.

Comment: My app does not stream audio through devices connected by bluetooth. It is only possible to play on speaker or devices connected to jack port.

Comment: You can achieve that by just checking the current route and observing route changes. There's no need to check all possible routes.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only `currentRoute` is available through the public API.